# Javascript form onclick

Tags: javascript, forms

I have this js code i need to search the form on keyup create code fences with backticks ` or tildes ~:

```
//input form-control
     $('.textbox[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
                /* Get input value on change */
                var firld= $(this).append();

                var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
                if(inputVal.length >=1){
                     $('#kbUP').empty();

                        $('#kb').append();
                    });
                } else{
                     $('#kbUP').append();
                }
            });



//End of code
```

Answer (score 1):

Create another event for keydown and check if pressed keyCode is 13 https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

But I don't understand why you want to click button or use enter when you are searching in each keyup

Comment: event.keyCode is deprecated now. The recommended method is `event.code == "Enter"`. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code.)